# Have issues to make paytm payment integration live in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, paytm

For Test MID I am able to pay successfully but when i try to make it live with my production key and production MID of paytm i am getting error of 'Invalid: This MID is not available on our staging environment' and i am using 'https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=' callback url for production as instuction given for paytm but still i am not able to make payment in production environment. Below is my flutter code :

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String payment_response = '';
  final String M_ID = "";      //Production MID
  final String CHANNEL_ID = "WAP";// type here your channel id given by paytm
  final String INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = "Retail";  // type here your industry type id given by paytm
  final String WEBSITE = "DEFAULT";    //for production

  TextEditingController amountController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Paytm example app'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: amountController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Amount',
                  prefix: Text('Rs. '),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //Firstly Generate CheckSum bcoz Paytm Require this
                  generateCheckSum();
                },
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text(
                  "Pay Now",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              Text('Response: $payment_response\n'),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void generateCheckSum() async {
    var url =
        'https://promiseacademy.co.in/flutterapp/paytm/generateChecksum.php';

    String orderId = DateTime
        .now()
        .millisecondsSinceEpoch
        .toString();

    String callBackUrl =
    'https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=' +
        orderId;

    //Please use your parameters here
    //CHANNEL_ID etc provided to you by paytm

    final response = await http.post(url, headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }, body: {
      "M_ID": M_ID,
      "CHANNEL_ID": CHANNEL_ID,
      'INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID': INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID,
      'WEBSITE': WEBSITE,
      'TXN_AMOUNT': amountController.text,
      'CALLBACK_URL': callBackUrl,
      'ORDER_ID': orderId,
      'CUST_ID': '1',
    });

    //for Testing(Stagging) use this

    //https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=

    //https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = json.decode(response.body);

      print("Response :" + response.body + "\nchecksumhash:" + result['CHECKSUMHASH']);

      var paytmResponse = Paytm.startPaytmPayment(
          true,
          M_ID,
         orderId,
          "1",
          CHANNEL_ID,
          amountController.text,
          WEBSITE,
          callBackUrl,
          INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID,
          result['CHECKSUMHASH']);

      paytmResponse.then((value) {
        setState(() {
          payment_response = value.toString();
        });
      });
    }
    else{
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 var paytmResponse = Paytm.startPaytmPayment(
          true,
          M_ID,
         orderId,
          "1",
          CHANNEL_ID,
          amountController.text,
          WEBSITE,
          callBackUrl,
          INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID,
          result['CHECKSUMHASH']);
```

Please change first parameter to false from true in Paytm.startPaytmPayment(). That parameter indicates isTesting. If you keep true, it is taking staging details and giving you error for production details not found.